Kali Linux - Fresh install with everything by default shows *only* wallpaper on boot
I just installed the Kali Linux on a Lenovo T61 laptop with broken screen - I use external VGA/D-SUB monitor in order to work.
Installed on a 128 GB USB drive, made with Rufus (Rufu 3.4.1430) ...
Previously on the laptop there were again Kali Linux (older version) with Windows 10 on dual boot.
Now Kali is the only OS that is installed, but it doesn't seem to be OK.
The machine/OS responds to right clicks, show context menus and dialog boxed/windows, but not the main OS GUI...
Update: It seems that when I choose output mode "VGA-1" in Panel Settings - the top GUI panel/taskbar appears... or when I select "Span monitors"...
Other "non-visible" windows such as the Terminal are only partly and hardly visible when I hold Alt-Tab... but not really on focus/visible... they work though, I can execute commands and so on...
P.S: I tried to sudo apt install gnome (not apt-get) from another question and when I restarted, it showed me another logo, not the one of Linux on the welcome screen...
Kali Linux won't boot to GUI

If you're asking this question... Kali is not for you and Linux beginner questions about Kali are quite frown upon here . Make sure to READ and UNDERSTAND both links.

OK, I agree with you... at least on some things.
I don't have enough knowledge even for the standard Linux distros, but I want to experiment...
In the end, I just used a Live Kali from a USB Flash drive that I plugged into my main PC, not the laptop and everything works just fine.
